# I can freely choose the operating system on company workstation. Any workplace concerns to be aware of?

Tags: software-industry, germany, software

I'm taking a new job soon. The new company will let me install any operating system of my choice on the company workstation. At my current job, I was given a choice between Ubuntu and MacOS, so I am unfamiliar with having completely free rein.

I use Gentoo exclusively as my daily driver at home, so I'm very familiar with it and prefer it as an OS at work as well. I'm concerned if this would cause any audit/compliance issues. I know Ubuntu has some certifications that Gentoo does not. (Jurisdiction: Germany (EU), Operating Area: Media Sales Platform)

I will clear up the compliance/policy issues with my manager, but I was wondering if there are any concerns that I hadn't thought of, such as:

- Is it generally a bad idea for any other reason, besides compliance/security concerns?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off topic because you should discuss this with your company. Beyond that, compatibility and security concerns of different operating systems is off topic and compliance would be extremely company-specific (unless you mean legal compliance, in which case that's probably off topic too and more the company's problem than yours).

Comment: This question was previously more technical and comments on that part of it were [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68804/discussion-on-question-by-user79637-i-can-freely-choose-the-operating-system-on). Please take any technical questions or discussions to that chatroom.

Comment: You talk a lot about what you use at home (irrelevant) and at your past job (irrelevant). What about the work you have to do in the new company? What about the projects? I mean, even if you do web work only in angular, if the main project is in .NET - being able to run Visual Studio is a BIG plus. And you say nothing about that. Start investigating the landscape you have to work with. Take it from there.

Comment: @TomTom The OS a person uses in other contexts, and has used previously, is relevant because it dictates what they are most likely to be already versed in. That type of knowledge definitely crosses between use cases.

Comment: Not if the company has a standard and applications that may or may not run on this OS at all. Unless this person is willing to pay for a consultant to handle each and every problem - at market rates, because an external consultant will have to be brought in - it is VERY relevant to the business to maintain standardization.

Answer (score 16):

If you intend to choose an OS that no one else at your company uses you should ask your manager if he has any objections to your choice, or if there is a standard configuration used by members of his team filling your role.

> Is it generally a bad idea for any other reason, besides
>   compliance/security concerns?

Seeking the input of your new peers is always a good idea in this scenario.  This way any advantages to *their* configuration can be accounted for.  Also make sure that you consider any **compatibility, ongoing maintenance, or security issues** during your decision making process.

And finally, remember to take into account *this new to you* environment.  Most likely they are doing most things for a reason.

Comment: In addition to compatability issues, if you're the only one using an OS, you need to do _all_ your own maintenance and troubleshooting.

Comment: @Erik this might however also be an advantage - depending on what tasks are available in the new team and what you like. If you demonstrate some level of expertise with a particular OS, your manager might think of you first for any tasks that are OS-specific, say server administration when your are the only one with a Linux or bug reproduction when you are the only one with a Windows (and you got a bug from a user that has the same Windows running).

Comment: "Seeking the input of your new peers is always a good idea in this scenario." <- This is bad advise unless you work at some kind of tech company.  The average employee in most industries is more likely to give you bad or incomplete suggestions than looking up the answer to the problem online from people who have actual backgrounds in this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

They're multiple problematic that have to be handled if you use your own OS :

- **Compatibility with the Information System of the company**. To access internet you may have trouble if you're using Linux based distribution and the proxy server of the company is Windows-Kerberos based. However if the company allow any kind of OS, they should have think about this kind of trouble before hand.
- **Compatibility with co-worker of the same project**. If every developer set up their own development you might have trouble finding why it isn't working on your own station.
- **Company support**. If you have trouble to access some resources in the company, of if some intranet website doesn't work (because they're IE based) the IT support might refuse to support you.

Depending of the information system of you company you may be able :

- To run under Linux without trouble
- Need a Windows VM to access some specific resources
- Need Windows as main OS and use Linux VM hoping your computer is powerfull enough to run a full IDE within a VM (for me, it is not even that much the case without the VM layer).

My advice is that unless you're really sure of what you're doing, stick to something commonly used in the company.

Comment: Actually it is 2017. If there is any interop, the bestter answer is to run windows - and then use the Linux Subsystem that can be installed as a feature of windows to run Linux build tools. No VM's required. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10 - title "Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux".

Comment: It is possible that they're not under W10 though, remember that companies are often 5/10y late. And it doesn't seems like you can run any Linux distrib but only those provided right ? But that's an interesting point I didn't know it existed.

Comment: but he says he is able to choose ;) Which makes the 5y point moot. Also any linux distro - remember, in this scenario you do not really run UI elements on linux. It is perfectly fine for example as a compilation platform ;) That is what MS uses it. Add support for docker (also in windows) and you have all that you need to compile and prepare docket images in windows that then get uploaded (or you can actually run them) to whatever kubernets you run ;)

Answer (score 1):

The boss told you that you can use whatever OS you prefer. So first you take this at face value and decide what you want (and you might have a second and third preference). Then you inform relevant people of your decision to give them a chance to object. Just because your boss allowed you that freedom doesn’t mean IT agrees, for example. They might say “we know what your boss says and he is just stupid. We have zero ability to support XYZ so we would be very, very happy if you chose something else and we can avoid a fight with him.”

Now you can switch to your second choice and make everyone happy with your choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it generally a bad idea for any other reason, besides compliance/security concerns?

One important thing to consider is the **compatibility** of the system of your choice **with the others available in the company**. Make sure that they can supply you with all the things you could need for your system regardless of the OS you chose. Also make sure that there will be no trouble accessing printers and similar devices with the OS of your choice. You could also try **ask your coworkers about the experience or considerations** they have had with the choice of OS they made.

This also depends on the gadgets, devices, libraries, etc., that you will need to use in the work you will perform. *Generally speaking* (and without promoting any tech feuds), there is a higher rate of compatibility amongst MacOS and Ubuntu than, say between any of those and Windows. This means that regardless of your choice, the differences if any, will probably be few.

I have not worked with Gentoo specifically, but seems that **it is a Linux distribution as well as Ubuntu** (Debian), so probably the **smoothest transition** for you is to chose Ubuntu if given the option.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Whatever OS you Know Best

For starters, I would double check that they REALLY means use whatever OS you like, because to a lot of less tech savvy people, that statement means you can use either Windows or Mac.

If your employer is infact not requiring, or even recommending any specific OS, it means that you probably will not have an IT department or IT service provider to lean on.  **This makes you solely responsible for your own IT**.  By picking the OS you know best, you are least likely to be inconvenienced by the lack of an IT provider.  Do not expect to rely on your coworkers unless your job is specifically in IT or a closely related field. It's better to look up answers to things you don't already know than it is to ask them for IT advise.  Asking someone who is not a specialist is likely to do more harm than good; so, there is no benefit it trying to use the same OS as them or rely on them to help you with your problems.

As for your compliance concerns, compliance standards like GDPR, HIPPA, NIST, etc. are written to define goals, not what software you need to use to meet those goal. This is because most western nations like Germany have anti-monopoly laws that prevent legislation from requiring specific software to meet compliance standards. In general, any OS that is able to receive regular security patches can meet any legally required compliance standard you need to worry about unless you live in certain countries like China where specific OSes are banned by law for political reasons.

*Myself, and I believe a few other people have misread this question at first, so to clarify, his NEW employer is not recommending any specific OS.  Ubuntu and MacOS were recommended by his old employer so they have nothing to do with the question.*

Answer (score -2):

Remember that you might find it hard, or sometimes impossible, to use the company VPN and Active Directory controlled systems when you use a less common OS. Be ready to spend weeks in getting everything working. In worst case scenarios, you will be ordered by your boss to "stop playing around and get it working". Which usually ends up meaning: install Windows. If you are lucky, you can replace your company laptop with a Mac after the fact, if you don't want to use Windows.

Comment: I have yet to come across a company where Linux is the predominant OS, or even widely used, in employee computers. And I've worked and interviewed in companies from startups to Fortune 500. Personally I prefer Linux, but of course the workplace is the one that decides what you must use.

Comment: @Juha_Untinen Well, from the one's I interviewed with I got quite mixed answers on that topic - but I wouldn't go by that alone (is allowed vs. reality etc.). In my last company Linux was the norm amongst developers and some guys even had to switch from Windows to Linux to integrate into the normal infrastructure. In research I've only seen Windows machines in the secretaries office. All in all I've been in more places with Linux predominance (in development) than Windows. I didn't even care in the beginning, but now a decent Linux option is a must for any job.

Comment: @Darkwing Which means install windows. Then install Linux Subsystem to get an integrated Ubuntu without the use of a VM ;)

Comment: @JuhaUntinen That is culture specific.  In the USA, yes its all Windows and Mac unless you are running a server, but Germany, where the OP is, has the highest Linux usage out of any Western Nation; so, Linux is much more popular there for personal and business use than most places.